# How can solve this compiling error?

Tags: ios, linker

I'm making a application that uses the mongoose source to run a web server on iOS devices. I ran make to make the files necessary and added them to the project. It compiles just fine but when it gets to the linking portion it throws the following error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/tyler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iServer-gnfryiiydesjxicyoqsybsqugulz/Build/Intermediates/iServer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iServer.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-111B0F2B16D0E565.o and /Users/tyler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iServer-gnfryiiydesjxicyoqsybsqugulz/Build/Intermediates/iServer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iServer.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-4AE49C4D6F0286C.o for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

any suggestions?

Comment: This is a link error, not a compile error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a web developer finally starting to work with iOS devices so whenever something happens when I click run I tend to assume its a compiling error. However I should of figured this out considering it occurred during the linking stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through your project files thoroughly and make sure you do not have 2 files named **`main.m`**. Remove the one that does not belong to your actual project.

Comment: I only have a main.c file. I take it my project needs a main.m file?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to check the supporting files folder. I have a main.c file and a main.m file. Is that causing the error?

Comment: The compiler is complaining because it has duplicate **`main()`** calls. Your project needs it's original `main.m` which contains the only **main()** method. You must have an additional library (or added project) that contains another main file (in your case you say `main.c`. If this main.c belongs to a different project, you should remove it.

Comment: main.c belongs to the mongoose source. If i renamed it do you think that would solve it?

Comment: No, because the main method will still exist. I would remove that main.c since you are not compiling mongoose as your main project.

Comment: Thank you, it finally compiled! :)

Comment: Great, thats what we're here for!

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with mongoose, but projects often have test apps that test the library. That's probably the source of the extra `main()` that's being linked. Like WrightsCS said, it's probably in a main.m file, but if not, search for `main(`.